# Stuck in a toll booth

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

Got to a toll booth. Hit enter to get the ticket. The gate opened.

And my heavy load decides to pull me backwards. Before I can get my truck to move forwards again, the gate has closed. And won't open again.

Now I'm stuck between a closed gate (can't retake the ticket) and heavy traffic behind me. How do I get out?

Comment: What kind of truck are you using?  What country toll is it?

Comment: @TimmyJim The one east of Metz. The truck's FH16 Classic, 4x2 chassis, 600 hp and  2800 Nm engine. I'm hauling 22t of Logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, booted up the game to answer a question. As I loaded into the game proper, the gate was open again, and I was able to drive through it.

So, in short, *restart*. A quick load or something similar might also work.

Comment: I read that certain trucks have been known to glitch like this too in certain booths which is why I asked